# How to calculate the formation energy of a monolayer using VASP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I want to calculate the `formation energy` of ***WS2 monolayer*** unit cell using `VASP`. I am wandering if you could show me *the detailed calculation steps* in `VASP` to do that for WS2 or any monolayer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure whether there is a special point about monolayer. The steps to calculate the formation energy are following (This is suitable for bulk materials):

- Calculate the total energy of primitive monolayer WS2: $E$(WS2)
- Calculate the total energy per atom for the lowest-energy configuration bulk S: $E$(S)
- Calculate the total energy per atom for the lowest-energy configuration bulk W: $E$(W)
- Estimate the formation energy: $$\Delta E_f=E(\text{WS2})-\dfrac{1}{3}E(\text{W})-\dfrac{2}{3}E(\text{S}).$$

Reference paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0966979509000892

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am wandering if you could just show me how calculate the total energy per atom for the lowest-energy configuration bulk "S and W". Should I do relaxation then SCF ? Which structure should I put for bother "S and W" ?
Thanks in advance, and you were helpful as always.

Comment: @ChiKou S: https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-96/ . W: https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-91/